# I'm having the following issues when trying to access MySQL on my Win10

Tags: database-connection

```
MySQL Service detected with wrong path
10:34:59 a. m.  [mysql]     Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
10:34:59 a. m.  [mysql]     Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
10:34:59 a. m.  [mysql]     Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 6.0\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 6.0\my.ini" MySQL
10:34:59 a. m.  [mysql]     Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
10:34:59 a. m.  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
```

And the MySQL error log

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835037
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2017-10-03 11:25:56 2118 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-10-03 11:25:56 8472 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2017-10-03 11:25:56 8472 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-10-03 11:25:56 8472 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-10-03 11:25:56 8472 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-10-03 11:25:56 8472 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-10-03 11:25:56 8472 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-10-03 11:25:56 8472 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-10-03 11:25:56 8472 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-10-03 11:25:56 8472 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-10-03 11:25:57 8472 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-10-03 11:26:00 8472 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-10-03 11:26:00 8472 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-10-03 11:26:00 8472 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 1835037
2017-10-03 11:26:00 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-10-03 11:26:00 8472 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-10-03 11:26:01 8472 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-10-03 11:26:03 8472 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.21-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2017-10-03 13:51:17 574 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1835037 and 1835037 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1836205 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-10-03 13:51:17 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-10-03 13:51:18 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2017-10-03 13:51:18 1396 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2017-10-03 13:51:20 1396 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-10-03 13:51:20 1396 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-10-03 13:51:20 1396 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 1836205
2017-10-03 13:51:20 236 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-10-03 13:51:20 1396 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-10-03 13:51:20 1396 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-10-03 13:51:21 1396 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.21-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what specific results did you get.

Comment: I want to make connection between xampp and MySQL. 
Change the default port.
Restart my pc, yesterday afternoon everything was fine but today started with the error

Comment: Details like these should be in the body of the question!

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the first time I ask for help

Comment: I'm suggesting how you can make the question better, so it is more likely to attract good answers and be more useful for others. Note that you can [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46590268/edit) the question.

Comment: I am making a web, for that I use the database connection between MySQL and xampp, yesterday when I install MySQL and xampp everything worked fine, the hosting port of xampp is 3306 and the port of MySQL the 3307, I can not now set the xampp connection with my database

Comment: These are the sorts of details that should be **in the body of the question**.

Comment: In control panel xampp I get this [main]  Initializing Modules
MySQL Service detected with wrong path
Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 6.0\bin\mysqld" 
[mysql]  Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
[main]  Starting Check-Timer
[main]  Control Panel Ready
[Apache] Attempting to start Apache app...
[Apache] Status change detected: running
[mysql]  Attempting to start MySQL service...
..

Comment: [Please edit the question and put these details in there, not in comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46590268/edit)